# Using a Service in AngularJS to Share Data

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am attempting to set the browser title for a SPA based on the route (state) by using a service to set a variable that is then updated by the controller for each page as it is loaded.  So far the variable is being set in the service when a page is loaded however the title is not updated for the SPA.

My `index.html` is defined as follows;

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="rbApp" ng-controller="mainController as mainVm">
<head>
    <title>{{mainVm.pageTitle}}</title>
    <!-- CSS files used in the application are referenced here -->
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Navigation elements (Bootstrap navbar, mennu items, etc are placed in this section) -->
    <!-- Content -->
    <div ui-view></div>
    <!-- Footer (common elements for the footer are placed here)-->

    <!-- 3rd Party Scripts -->
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Services -->
    <script src="App/Common/common.services.js"></script>

    <!-- Application Scripts -->
    <script src="App/Common/rbApp.js"></script>
    <script src="App/Common/mainController.js"></script>
    <script src="App/WebSite/homeController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My routing is defined in `rbApp.js` as follows;

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module("rbApp", ['ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', "common.services"]);

    app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider", function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

        $stateProvider
        .state("home", {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl: "App/WebSite/home.html",
            controller: "homeController as homeVm"
        })
        /*
            Other states used by the application are entered here...
        */
    }]);
})();
```

The `mainController` for `index.html` is defined as follows;

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module("rbApp").controller("mainController", ["$scope", "sharedServices", mainController]);

    function mainController($scope, sharedServices) {
        var vm = this;

        $scope.$on("updatePageTitle"), function () {
            vm.pageTitle = sharedServices.getPageTitle();
            console.log("Updated 'vm.pageTitle'");
        }
    };
})();
```

The `sharedServices` service is coded as follows;

```
(function (undefined) {
    "use strict";

    var common = angular.module("common.services", ["ngResource"]);

    common.factory("sharedServices", ["$rootScope", sharedServices]);

    function sharedServices($rootScope) {
        var pageTitle = "";
        var pageName = "";

        var setPageTitle = function (title) {
            pageTitle = "Company Name - " + title;
            console.log("Broadcast 'updatePageTitle'");
            $rootScope.$broadcast("updatePageTitle");
        };
        var getPageTitle = function () {
            return pageTitle;
        };
        var setPageName = function (name) {
            pageName = name;
            $rootScope.$broadcast("updatePageName");
        };
        var getPageName = function () {
            return pageName;
        };
        return {
            setPageTitle: setPageTitle,
            getPageTitle: getPageTitle,
            setPageName: setPageName,
            getPageName: getPageName
        };
    }
})();
```

and the `homeController` is defined as;

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("common.services").controller('homeController', ["sharedServices", homeController]);

    function homeController(sharedServices) {
        var vm = this;
        sharedServices.setPageTitle("This is the new page title");
    }
})();
```

The `console.log` shows the variable in `sharedServices` being updated however the `sharedServices.getPageTitle()` function is never executed.

I have used `$rootScope.$broadcast` in other projects to share data in this manner but the `$scope.$on("updatePageTitle")` code in `mainController`isn't being triggered in this application?

Comment: Normally in an *event bus* setup, wouldn't you have your `$rootScope` subscribe to the event?  I don't see the issue with `$scope` listening for it, but in the rare instances where I want to have an *event bus*, I stick exclusively with `$rootScope`.

Comment: @jakeed1 presents a good solution for setting the title.  However, the issue you are actually attempting to debug (handler not running), I can't find an issue.  I set up a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BenbQmHHz3hQGZnqdKxH?p=preview) of something similar, and it seems to work fine.  Perhaps some kind of live demo would help track down the problem?

Comment: Oh, and what version of angular are you using?  It may make a difference.

Comment: I recommend using an IDE like Webstorm or at least a code linter, you will not run in to simple typo errors like the one outlined in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work just fine. In your scenario, the `$scope` associated with `MainController` is a child of the `$rootScope` so it should hear the event when it is broadcast.

What seems to be going on is that you have a typo in `MainController` that is not throwing any exceptions. Notice the misplaced close parentheses after "updatePageTitle":

```
$scope.$on("updatePageTitle"), function () {
    vm.pageTitle = sharedServices.getPageTitle();
    console.log("Updated 'vm.pageTitle'");
}
```

It should be changed to this:

```
$scope.$on("updatePageTitle", function () {
    vm.pageTitle = sharedServices.getPageTitle();
    console.log("Updated 'vm.pageTitle'");
});
```